# View presenters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvp

I recently saw an episode on presenters from scratch by Ryan Bates, it's a great explanation of what the presenter does. This is what I'm referring to :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

So I decided to refactor a bit some of my views because there were some really complicated logic inside.

I have a page in my app that displays the list of users along with their images etc. So what I did was that I rendered a partial for every user and that is how it worked.

After refactoring with presenters I've got the same one partial but all logic is moved outside to the presenter, and the view just displays the values, however I noticed that rendering the partial for each user takes as twice as much as it did before.

This is before (data from logs):

```
Rendered users/_user_thumb.html.haml (6.4ms)
```

After refactoring :

```
Rendered users/_user_thumb.html.haml (18.5ms)
```

I've looked at the logs are there some extra queries that get trigger or something, and there is no extra queries fired when the code was refactored.

My question is why is it so slow? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is how my code looks now :

```
 - @users.each do |user|
   = render_partial "user_thumb", user: user
```

Now inside the render partial `user_thumb` I had a complex logic, but now I have this :

```
- present user do |user_presenter|
  ....mycode here
```

I use haml.

**QUESTION UPDATE**

Billy had some good points in his answer so I voted up his answer.

I tried his suggestion to decorate the `@users` in the controller like :

```
@users = UserDecorator.decorate(users)
```

And then I then I try to inspect it and I see something like :

```
#<UserDecorator:0x0000000966a6f8 @object=[#<User id: 8112 .....some users ], @context={}>
```

Which was good cause I seem to get my users decorated at once. Then I tried the suggestion from Billy and did :

```
= render partial: "user_thumb", collection: @users
```

But then when I tried in my view :

```
collection.each do |u|
  puts "#{user.inspect}"
end
```

My decorator looks like :

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates :user
  ....
end
```

I get the user instead of decorated user why is that? How does this work when decorating a list of objects? What is the purpose of that if at the end you still get the user objects?

This works but it's really slower :

```
- @users.each do |user|
       = render_partial "user_thumb", user: user.decorate
```

How does one create array of decorators?

Comment: I'd imagine this probably has something to do with the number of records in `@users` that are being iterated through. Has the number of users increased?

Comment: no, I'm using the exact same dataset. thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several places to improve the code.

Firstly, make sure your `@users` is already decorated in controller before passing to view. Benefits:

1. By this you don't need to edit original template at all, just use same `@users`.
2. Your view is decoupled from whatever present/decorate pattern you use, and there are really lots of options. You can also opt not to use it with views untouched.
3. Theoritially this should be faster because if you decorate items seperately in view, computer need to load the related modules again and again, comparing with doing in a batch.

Secondly, render a `collection` instead of iterating views. In my experience this is faster.

Instead of

```
- @users.each do |user|
   = render_partial "user_thumb", user: user
```

Do

```
= render partial: "user_thumb", collection: @users
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate on this "make sure your users is already decorated in controller before passing to view". I'm using presenters, not decorators. Although they are both form of decorator pattern, there is a difference

Comment: @HereToLearn, I use Draper gem, so I just output `@users.decorate`. Even you use other solutions, you can also output `@users = present(@users)` in last step in controller. If your presenter can't process a collection, better to improve it.

Comment: That's an excellent point, I do need to improve it, too bad the original rails cast, doesn't say how to do it. I guess I'll have to find for myself, if you got any suggestions that' be great. thanks

Comment: The cast is good for learning the idea from scratch. For usage you can check an existing gem or improve the idea.

Comment: one more thing, I think I know what you mean now. I've found a draper a good choice for this kind of things, and I decorate my objects all in the controller as you say, but when I .each over collection in the user_thumb I still get user objects rather than decorators